# OSError importing python-igraph

Tags: python, igraph, cairo, pycairo

I am trying to import `igraph` but it keeps throwing this error at me:

```
>>> import igraph

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/igraph/__init__.py", 
line 36, in <module>
    from igraph.clustering import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/igraph/clustering.py", 
line 36, in <module>
    from igraph.drawing.colors import ClusterColoringPalette
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/igraph/drawing/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from igraph.drawing.graph import DefaultGraphDrawer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/igraph/drawing/graph.py", line 27, in <module>
    from igraph.drawing.edge import ArrowEdgeDrawer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/igraph/drawing/edge.py", 
line 17, in <module>
    cairo = find_cairo()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/igraph/drawing/utils.py", line 413, in find_cairo
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cairocffi/__init__.py", 
line 41, in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(ffi, 'cairo', 'cairo-2')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cairocffi/__init__.py", 
 line 38, in dlopen
    raise OSError("dlopen() failed to load a library: %s" % ' / 
'.join(names))
OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2
```

1. I have tried to follow [this guide](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/installation---osx) to install `cairo` but it throws this error and doesn't solve the `igraph` import issue: `error: mandatory image surface backend feature could not be enabled`
2. I have also tried to install `pycairo` but that resulted in `no module founds: cairo`, which brought me back to square one.
3. I tried running `sudo port install cairo` as per https://cairographics.org/download/ instructions. But that results in `Error: Port cairo not found`

---

My sys config:

- MacOS High Sierra 10.13.1
- Python 3.6
- python-igraph 0.7.1

I am clueless as to what can be the issue. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: I presume you tried the solution given in the guide you posted that explicitly mentions `error: mandatory image surface backend feature could not be enabled` and how to fix it?

Comment: @roganjosh yeah, it didn't help

Comment: have you tried to install igraph with homebrew and then `pip install python-igraph`? It described in [official guide for mac os](http://igraph.org/python/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Aiven I have managed to solve my issue. If anyone ever comes across the same problem, this have done the trick for me:

```
brew install cairo
brew install py2cairo
brew install igraph  (install C-core)
sudo pip install python-igraph (install igraph for python)
```